# chrome.devtools.panels.create is undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to create a Chrome extension and want to in different ways interact with the devtools. To create a foundation I decided to follow [this guide](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/devtools-panels), however it doesn't seem to be working at all. The errors arrive from this piece of code:

```
chrome.devtools.panels.create(
  "My Panel",
  "/icons/star.png",
  "/devtools/panel/panel.html"
).then((newPanel) => {
  newPanel.onShown.addListener(handleShown);
  newPanel.onHidden.addListener(handleHidden);
});
```

The errors:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')
> Ignoring unauthorized client request from null

A panel is successfully created however when trying to view it just says "It may have been moved, edited or deleted". If instead of doing then add a callback function. The `TypeError` is removed, but the `Ignoring unauthorized client request` persists.

This is my first time working with Chrome extensions or anything with devtools API, however I have not been able to find any sufficient help online.

Comment: This is a Firefox extension, not a Chrome extension. To use it in Chrome you need to add WebExtension polyfill.

Comment: @wOxxOm I tried using this extension for Firefox instead but I get the same result, my panel is showing, but there is no content when clicked. The only difference being that the icon for the panel is successfully loaded and that there are no error messages in the console.

Comment: Did you install it via `about:debugging` page?

Comment: @wOxxOm yep as an temporary extension